# Total demand under logit model

Tags: pricing, market

The setting is simple, i.e. formula for demand of service/product is linear
$$
  d = \alpha - \beta p
$$
where $ \alpha $ is maximum demand, $ \beta $ is some coefficient, and $ p $ is price. There are two firms, with different prices $p_1$ and $ p_2 $, and the prices are fixed, so there is no competition. The fraction of total demand is captured by the logit rule (price-oriented)
$$
  f = \frac{e^{-\gamma p_1}}{e^{-\gamma p_1} + e^{-\gamma p_2}}
$$ 
where $ \gamma $ is some sensitivity coefficient.

**Question**: how can I estimate total demand in this setting?

EDIT: I found an answer by my own, but I'm not sure if it is OK. The answer is the solution of this, I belive, transcedent equation
$$
  d = \beta - \beta \ln q + \beta \ln (\alpha (e^{-p_1} + e^{-p_2}))
$$